# Error When Running Released Version of Kibana (ZeroClipboard)

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, zeroclipboard, kibana-4

So I'm running Kibana on a server in the cloud and I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: Uncaught ReferenceError: ZeroClipboard is not defined (http://.../index.js?_b=6004:89886)
    at window.onerror (http://.../index.js?_b=6004:45829:24)
```

I've googled this and I've only found people talking about this issue on pre-release versions of Kibana. I'm running version 4.0.2 and I get the same issue when I run 4.0.1. Anyone see this before?

Here's a public url to my kibana server: http://52.7.27.45:5601/

**UPDATE:**

kibana.yml

```
port: 5601
host: "0.0.0.0"
elasticsearch_url: "http://...:9200"
elasticsearch_preserve_host: true
kibana_index: ".kibana"
default_app_id: "discover"
ping_timeout: 300000
request_timeout: 300000
shard_timeout: 0
verify_ssl: true
```

**Update 2:**

I just tried running kibana on the same instance as one of my elasticsearch nodes and I didn't get this error. This seems to be related to running kibana on a host that isn't running an elasticsearch node. Seems crazy to me...

Comment: Can you put here your `config.js` file?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not too familiar with the Kibana package... where would I find the config.js file?

Comment: Is kibana.yml what you're looking for?

Comment: It was `kibana.yml`, sorry. @threejeez

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar problem in the past and I believe the plugins are not being loaded and in the `kibana.yml`, you should have the following:

```
# Plugins that are included in the build, and no longer found in the plugins/ folder
bundled_plugin_ids:
 - plugins/dashboard/index
 - plugins/discover/index
 - plugins/doc/index
 - plugins/kibana/index
 - plugins/markdown_vis/index
 - plugins/metric_vis/index
 - plugins/settings/index
 - plugins/table_vis/index
 - plugins/vis_types/index
 - plugins/visualize/index
```

Related: https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/2617

Comment: TL;DR This worked... thanks for the help! It's funny... I dropped this a while back because it wasn't much of a priority. It just became a priority again and I was back where I left off with this problem. So, I took to google and found this question and thought this answer would be worth trying. Then I realized that it was ME who asked the question and had a bit of a laugh.